# How to you sort and then make an unmodifiable of type HashMap<String, HashMap<Path, HashSet<Integer>>>?

Tags: java, collections, nested, hashset, inverted-index

I am building an inverted index in Java. I already have the structure populated with data from files read. Now I want sort all three levels of the structure and then create an unmodifiable copy of it to return to another class for writing it to a file. Ideally I could use the `Collections.sort()` and the `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` / `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` functions. And no, I do not want to use a TreeSet.

Current code:

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap<Path, HashSet<Integer>>> getInvertedIndex()
{

    // sortInvertedIndex();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<Path, HashSet<Integer>>> copyOfInvertedIndex = null;

    // Set<String> words = invertedIndex.keySet();
    Set<Entry<String, HashMap<Path, HashSet<Integer>>>> m = invertedIndex.entrySet();

    // copyOfInvertedIndex = Collections.unmodifiableMap(invertedIndex);
    return copyOfInvertedIndex;
}

public void sortInvertedIndex()
{

    // List words = new List();
    // Collections.addAll(words, invertedIndex.keySet());
    // invertedIndex.keySet();
    // // SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(myHashMap.keySet());
    // // SortedSet<String> values = new
    // TreeSet<String>(myHashMap.values());
    // Collections.sort(list);

}
```

Comment: This is too broad. What do you want to sort? How do you want to sort it?

Comment: I want to sort all three levels. So for the first level of HashMap<String> by alphabetically. For the second level of HashMap<Path> I want to sort if also alphabetically. I could convert it to a string. It is for the fileName that the String word above holds. And for the third level of HashSet<Integer> I would like it sorted from smallest to biggest. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: What have you written and tried so far?

Comment: Updating my answer to include code :))

Comment: What do you call "sorted"? `HashMap` is not expected to preserve order over its keys or values. Returning a "sorted" `HashMap` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I only call this function after scanning all files and populating the invertedIndex and therefore do not care about preserving its order before nor after this method call.

Comment: @tcsiwula Why don't you want to use `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`? You're only able to sort a `List` via `Collection::sort`. You also should consider using Interfaces as return value and variable type.

Comment: @Flown - I would rather incur the cost at the moment the sort is required, not upfront. Can you convert a HashMap/HashSet into into there respective keySet/valueSet and then use Collections.sort with out losing their mappings? Please link me to something about what you are describing about for the Interfaces as return value and variable type. Thanks much!

Comment: By using interfaces i.e. `public Map<String, Map<Path, Set<Integer>>> getInvertedIndex()`. You should hide the implementation detail.

Comment: Ahhhh good call, thanks @Flown